# Approximate quadratic Bezier with circle SDF function

Tags: algorithm, graphics, geometry, interpolation, bezier

**Summary:**
I have an triangle with points at specified positions, they all have `F` signed distance field value, this field is lineary interpolated between each other point and used to get the distance by `D = 1.0 - sqrt(F.x * F.x + F.y * F.y)` function that evaluated for each pixel in that triangle. There's also SDF limits variables, `S=thickness/radius` - start cutoff distance, `E=0.5/(thickness+radius)` - end cutoff distance, where `thickness=1.0; radius=25.0`. If `D >= S && D <= E` color of pixel is red, otherwise it's discarded. The green line is quadratic bezier curve with same points positions as triangles just for showcase.

[image: Showcase]

**Issue:** How do I can compute 'F' variable of points to adjust red line near the green? It is also possible to add points to triangle and/or translate their positions if required.

Comment: There's quite a few really solid hits when you search the web for "SDF for quadratic bezier", did none of those help?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans most of those are about changing the SDF function, that is not a way for me.

Comment: Is it possible to simply consider adjusting the F value at 2 points A and C to make their D value to be some valid value?
For example, deciding the target D value to 0.03, it seems to be able to decide 2 F values to { ( 9.97, 0 ) and ( -9.97, 0 ) }.
And then adjusting only the remaining F value at point B.

Comment: @fana I don't quite understand what you mean, the `D` value is based on the length of the `F` value at current processed pixel that interpolated between all points (at least 3, couldn't be less) in that triangle/polygon.

Comment: The green curve pass through points A and C. So, I think, making the red curve to be so at first is one way. Is this already wrong?

Comment: @fana this is result with values you given: https://i.imgur.com/scNGeG3.png The value of `D` are equal to `F.x` at those points, this was expected and clear from its formula. And also broke the visualization since with `S=0.04` and `E=0.02` (evaluated from values in the question) it couldn't went right.